# Fundamental data type variables VS Object variables

Tags: c++

Recently I did a research concerning pointers in c++.

It is clear that pointers store an address of memory where the value is located whereas fundamental data type variables (int, float, boolean ...) store the value itself.

But what about object variables (Object myVariable)? What they hold in?

Comment: In short: they "hold" base-class subobjects and (non-static) member subobjects (member variables). Relevant Standard section: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#intro.object-2.

Comment: Not just to pick a nit, but according to the C++ Standard, an `int` is indeed an object.  You need to differentiate between an object in general and an object in the context of the C++ object model.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, "object" means anything represented as bytes in the abstract machine. You can have `int` objects, `char *` objects (which may point to `char` objects), `std::vector<std::string>` objects, etc.

The object representation of `class` types is not fully specified, but does include the representation of each base and data member.